# Should I use isolate scope in this case?

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing an custom input widget. The real code is more complex, but generally it looks like this:

```
app.directive('inputWidget', function () {
  return {
      replace:true,
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl:"inputWidget.html",
      compile: function (tElement, tAttributes){
          //flow the bindings from the parent.
          //I can do it dynamically, this is just a demo for the idea
          tElement.find("input").attr("placeholder", tAttributes.placeholder);
          tElement.find("input").attr("ng-model", tElement.attr("ng-model"));
      }
    };
});
```

inputWidget.html:

```
<div>
  <input />
  <span>
  </span>
</div>
```

To use it:

```
<input-widget placeholder="{{name}}" ng-model="someProperty"></input-widget>
```

The placeholder is displayed correctly with above code because it uses the same scope of the parent: http://plnkr.co/edit/uhUEGBUCB8BcwxqvKRI9?p=preview

I'm wondering if I should use an isolate scope, like this:

```
app.directive('inputWidget', function () {
      return {
          replace:true,
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl:"inputWidget.html",
          scope : {
              placeholder: "@"
              //more properties for ng-model,...
          }
      };
 });
```

With this, the directive does not share the same scope with the parent which could be a good design. But the problem is this isolate scope definition will quickly become messy as we're putting **DOM-related** properties on it (placeholder, type, required,...) and every time we need to apply a new directive (custom validation on the input-widget), we need to define a property on the isolate scope to act as **middle man**.

I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to always define isolate scope on directive components.

In this case, I have 3 options:

- Use the same scope as the parent.
- Use isolate scope as I said above.
- Use isolate scope but don't bind DOM-related properties to it, somehow flow the DOM-related properties from the parent directly. I'm not sure if it's a good idea and I don't know how to do it.

Please advice, thanks.

Comment: So, is the requirement that arbitrary attributes would apply to the `input` element in the template?

Comment: @New Dev: most of them do. This directive is just to add some more visual effects, the core functionality of the input should not change much.

Comment: you could use `scope: true` - it would inherit the outer scope

Comment: @New Dev: it does not work when there is a property in the directive scope that shadows the parent scope. For example: ng-model,.. We may have more cases like that.

Comment: How do you intend to use the directive? Are they meant to be reusable (then you can't make assumptions about scope variables)?

Comment: @New Dev: I want to make it reusable component. But the functionality is mostly the same as <input>, just add some visual effects. About `(then you can't make assumptions about scope variables)`, that's why I wonder whether it's a good idea to always use isolate scope.

Comment: Yes, because you can't assume that `{{name}}` will be available

Comment: @New Dev: the code that uses the widget should ensure that. It should be similar between `<input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="someProperty">` and `<input-widget placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="someProperty">`. The parent scope (controller is this case) should ensure these properties exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very trivial problem. This is because one could have arbitrary directives on the templated element that are presumably intended for `<input>`, and a proper solution should ensure that: 1) these directives compile and link only once and 2) compile against the actual `<input>` - not `<input-widget>`.

For this reason, I suggest using the actual `<input>` element, and add `inputWidget` directive as an attribute - this directive will apply the template, while the actual `<input>` element would host the other directives (like `ng-model`, `ng-required`, custom validators, etc...) that could operate on it.

```
<input input-widget
       ng-model="someProp" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
       ng-required="isRequired"
       p1="{{name}}" p2="name">
```

and `inputWidget` will use two compilation passes (modeled after `ngInclude`):

```
app.directive("inputWidget", function($templateRequest) {
  return {
    priority: 400,
    terminal: true,
    transclude: "element",
    controller: angular.noop,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      $templateRequest("inputWidget.template.html").then(function(templateHtml) {
        ctrl.template = templateHtml;
        transclude(scope, function(clone) {
          element.after(clone);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive("inputWidget", function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: -400,
    require: "inputWidget",
    scope: {
      p1: "@", // variables used by the directive itself
      p2: "=?" // for example, to augment the template
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      var templateEl = angular.element(ctrl.template);
      element.after(templateEl);
      $compile(templateEl)(scope);
      templateEl.find("placeholder").replaceWith(element);
    }
  };
});
```

The template (`inputWidget.template.html`) has a `<placeholder>` element to mark where to place the original `<input>` element:

```
<div>
  <pre>p1: {{p1}}</pre>
  <div>
    <placeholder></placeholder>
  </div>
  <pre>p2: {{p2}}</pre>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ujly5Fh6AdzRPePPRmdg?p=preview)

(EDIT) **Why 2 compilation passes**:

The solution above is a "workaround" that avoids a bug in Angular that was throwing with interpolate values being set on a comment element, which is what is left when `transclude: element` is used. This was fixed in [v1.4.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11038), and with the fix, the solution could be simplified to:

```
app.directive("inputWidget", function($compile, $templateRequest) {
  return {
    priority: 50, // has to be lower than 100 to get interpolated values
    transclude: "element",
    scope: {
      p1: "@", // variables used by the directive itself
      p2: "="  // for example, to augment the template
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      var dirScope = scope,
          outerScope = scope.$parent;

      $templateRequest("inputWidget.template.html").then(function(templateHtml) {
        transclude(outerScope, function(clone) {
          var templateClone = $compile(templateHtml)(dirScope);
          templateClone.find("placeholder").replaceWith(clone);
          element.after(templateClone);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfWfvC2HMHlv1Ojzho9V?p=preview)

Comment: very good idea of using transclude. But why do we need 2 `app.directive("inputWidget"` ? Can we just use one?

Comment: @KhanhTO, for some reason interpolation of `{{p1}}` expression was not working when `terminal: true` and `priority` is higher than 100. http://plnkr.co/edit/pEkRRsha1UP8r6XsQM9R?p=preview

Comment: @KhanhTO, v1.4.0-beta.6 fixed a problem that prevented a simpler approach. I updated the answer

Comment: thanks,That's what I was looking for: an isolate scope for the directive and parent scope for the `<input>`

Answer (score 2):

If the input-widget configuration is complex, I would use an options attribute, and also an isolated scope to make the attribute explicit and mandatory:

```
<input-widget options="{ placeholder: name, max-length: 5, etc }" 
   ng-model="name"></input-widget>
```

There is no need to flow any DOM attributes if you have the options model, and the ngModel:

```
app.directive('inputWidget', function () {
  return {
      replace:true,
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl:"inputWidget.html",
      scope: { options:'=', ngModel: '='}

    };
});
```

And in your template, you can bind attributes to your $scope view model, as you normally would:

```
<div>
  <input placeholder="{{options.placeholder}}" ng-model="ngModel"/>
  <span>
    {{options}}
  </span>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9n2GZ0GzxpxbP45HkFG?p=preview)

Personally, when developing for re-use, I prefer to use attributes as a means of configuring the directive and an isolated scope to make it more modular and readable. It behaves more like a component and usually without any need for outside context.

However, there are times when I find directives with child / inherited scopes useful. In those cases, I usually 'require' a parent directive to provide the context.  The pair of directives work together so that less attributes has to flow to the child directive.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, +1. I'm waiting to see whether there is a better suggestion